# Python - append data to a json file

Tags: python, json

I have the following data in my `c.json` file:

```
{
    "192.168.0.129": {
        "username": "me", 
        "streaming": "Spotify", 
        "name": "John", 
        "email": "john@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

and this other data that I want to append it to:

```
new_data = {'next_songs': ['song1', 'song2']}
```

for that purpose I'm doing this:

```
with open('c.json', 'r') as json_data: 
    data = json.load(json_data)

data.update(new_data)

with open('c.json', 'w') as json_data: 
    json.dump(data, json_data, indent=4)
```

this works, but no quite, because I get:

```
{
    "next_songs": [
        "song1", 
        "song2"
    ], 
    "192.168.0.129": {
        "username": "me", 
        "streaming": "Spotify", 
        "name": "John", 
        "email": "john@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

and I want  appended data to be a value under the key `"192.168.0.129"`, like so:

```
{
    "192.168.0.129": {
        "username": "me", 
        "streaming": "Spotify", 
        "name": "John", 
        "email": "john@gmail.com"
        "new_data": ["song1", "song2"], 
    }
}
```

how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a certain dict property `"192.168.0.129"`(which is the inner dict) should be updated, not the whole main dict:

```
...
data["192.168.0.129"].update(new_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may be updating the wrong dictionary

`data.update(new_data)` should be `data["192.168.0.129"].update(new_data)`